# Unity and Firebase: Enabling cross-app authentication with shared Apple Keychain?

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

How I can use cross-app authentication with shared Apple Keychain in Unity? Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/single-sign-on) it's only available for iOS. What about the Unity SDK?

I can find any related documentation nor methods to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been told from the Firebase Unity SDK that this feature is not yet available, so we will have to wait...

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/issues/873

Comment: Could you add a reference about the not yet available feaure?

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk/issues/873